# php Error: Resourse id #4

Tags: php

```
for($i = 0;$i<10;$i++)
        {
            $query1 ="SELECT `id` FROM radcheck ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;";
            $lololo= mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
            //echo $lololo;
            $query = "INSERT INTO radcheck (username,attribute,op,value) VALUES ('teleuser".$lololo."','Cleartext-Password',':=','$arr1[$i]')";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
```

I am trying to retrieve my latest id value to append with my username. And the value retrieve always be 'Resource id #4'.
Is there anyway to solve it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't quote `1` and `id` in single quotes, otherwise they'll be treated as string literals

Comment: I love sql error messages: *You have an error in your SQL syntax;* **check the manual** *that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax*

Comment: Select id from radcheck WHERE id=1 ORDER BY 'id' DESC ;

Comment: Select id from radcheck WHERE id=1 ORDER BY 'id' DESC ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql doesn't support `TOP` that is for `SQL Server`.
Instead of using `TOP` you can use mysql `LIMIT` so your query would be:

```
SELECT `id` FROM radcheck ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: it solve the syntax error but i got 'Resource id #4 '.

Comment: @KassieTeo Let me guess: You do: `echo $lololo;`, *right* ? -> You have to fetch your results

Comment: @Rizier123 Actually i wan to get my latest id value and append it with my username.

Comment: @KassieTeo If you want to get the latest id value it's better to use `MAX()` around `id` assuming it's auto_increment.

Comment: `echo $lololo;` <- I knew it! I'm so good with guessing, if this would only works if I play lottery..

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use single quotes around column names. if you need to escape it use backticks. And `TOP` is not mysql syntax. You have to use limit

```
SELECT `id` FROM radcheck ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 1
```

Do not longer use the depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @Daan Thanks for the hint. Have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'`s around field names -

```
"SELECT TOP 1 id FROM radcheck ORDER BY id DESC";
```

But as Daan told it will not work for `mysql`, then `ORDER` & `LIMIT` will do the trick.

```
"SELECT id FROM radcheck ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Why should it be like this? And not the other way?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes there are other ways. But the OP using this way.

Comment: it solve the syntax error but i got 'Resource id #4 '. how can i eliminate Resource id # ?

Comment: @KassieTeo you have to fetch the result alter executing the query. like - `mysql_fetch_object($lololo);`

Comment: @sgtBOSE i tried but it come with "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" .

Comment: change `_object` to `_array`.

Comment: Try with - `$result = mysql_fetch_object($lololo);` and the acces it with - `$result->id`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you never mind trying this pattern

```
 Select id from radcheck WHERE id=1 ORDER BY 'id' DESC ;
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.